# How to get started with SQLite, iCloud and CoreData?

Tags: core-data, xcode6, icloud

I am trying to follow Apple's Using the Sqlite Store with iCloud to add CoreData sharing between devices.  I'm on an outdated manual (2014-07-15) which, on page 8-9 shows how to enable iCloud in an existing app; however, the example is for documents, not for SQLite and when trying to enable for SQLite, the images are not up to date with XCode 6.
[image]

Can someone please tell me what I'm supposed to use (code-wise)  to get this started?

Comment: It sounds like you may be biting off more than you can chew -- consider a slightly simpler example app for starters.

Comment: What have you done so far, on the iPhone?

Comment: Nothing more than what you see above... it's an existing app, and from the instructions in the doc, I'm not sure how to enable iCloud for CoreData, since the instructions show how to set it up for documents, not SQLite.

Comment: Find an simple "hello world" tutorial and go through that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer here:

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Preparing_an_iOS_6_App_to_use_iCloud_Storage

It goes step-by-step to configure an app for using iCloud on multiple devices.